# Per thread memory allocation

Tags: c, memory-management, pthreads

I am working on a trace tool for multithread applications, more especially about memory allocation.

I would like a per thread memory allocation. I know that when a thread do a malloc, the memory used is the global heap. I would like to trace which thread allocated how much memory.

I did a wrapper upon malloc, incrementing values each time there is a malloc as:

```
void *mymalloc(size_t size) {
    mem_used[thread_id] += size;
    return malloc(size);
}
```

It works well. The problem is with `free` method, which does not return how much memory is released.

Don't take into account my solution, it is just to show what I tried.

EDIT:

As mentionned above, keeping my own table is a too heavy method.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

how about changing mymalloc to do:

```
int* mymem = malloc(size + sizeof(int)*2);
mymem[0] = thread_id;
mymem[1] = size;
mem_used[thread_id] += size;
return &mymem[2].
```

Then, in myfree(void* mem), you:

```
void myfree(void* mem)
{
    int* imem = (int*)(mem - sizeof(int)*2);
    int thread_id = imem[0];
    int size = imem[1];
    mem_used[thread_id] -= size;
    free(imem);
}
```

this can be optimized, but I hope you get the idea...

Comment: You allocated a memory area and returned 'allocated area address'+2*sizeof(int) so in myfree() the address you should pass to free() is 'the returned address from mymalloc()'-2*sizeof(int), which is 'imem'.

Comment: Nice solution, I like it! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The only think I can think of (although you probably considered this) is keeping an allocation table whit these columns:

- ThreadID (of course)
- Pointer
- Allocated size

Then, you will have to use your own **malloc** and **free** functions to do the actual mallocing and freeing, but also keeping the allocation table updated.

Is this for debugging purposes? Because otherwise, the overhead of maintaining this table can be significant.

Answer (score 0):

It's a little more complicated. Off the top-of-my-head:

- Create a map with the pointer value and memory size allocated for that pointer.
- In your `my_malloc`, update the map with the `size` argument.
- Write your own wrapper for `free` subtracting the `size` (which you retrieve by looking up the pointer value) for that thread.